# get contents of data grid view with Windows API

Tags: windows, vb.net, api

I am trying to see if there is a way to get the contents of a datagridview that is inside a top level window using Windows API's.  I am using Visual Basic for this, but could also use C.

Comment: Is the dgv in a different app?

Comment: what do you mean by top level window? Do you mean different form/Master page?

Comment: the dgv is in one app and my program is a separate app.  I am trying to read the contents of the dgv using Windows API's from the other app and display it in my app.

Comment: The WinAPI would get you the handle of the window, but I am not sure how you'd drill into a .NET dgv using it.  If you know some things about the other app, you might be able to use Reflection to get the info you want.

Comment: Thx.  Yes, I can already get the handle.  I am now trying to get the contents.  What is Reflection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you could use the WinAPI to drill into a .NET app's DGV to get any meaningful information.  But you might be able to using Reflection which  enables you to obtain information about assemblies and the types defined within them, such as classes, interfaces, and value types. The ops are contained in the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Its fairly slow, so it is often a last resort, and the methods and such are pretty dense (convoluted) because you are getting at the information the 'long way around' by examining the Types and then asking the type for information.

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14292/Runtime-Object-Editor) shows how to access information in a different executing assembly.  Given enough time and work and study, it should give you an idea how to do what you are asking.